¿Como hacer un boton que guarde memoria?
Quiero saber como puedo hacer un botón que me ayude a recopilar un numero y se guarde y cuando se presione otra vez me de el mismo numero guardado asi como un atajo.
Apenas soy nuevo en esto y también me seria de ayuda que me pudieran guiar a como consiguieron su respuesta
trate con if ... else pero aveces me da error cuando pongo el function
ya que lo que quiero es que me de un atajo al numero guardado


function agregarDisplay(value) {
  document.getElementById('display').value += value;
}

function limpiarDisplay() {
  document.getElementById('display').value = '';
}

function calcular() {
  let expression = document.getElementById('display').value;
  let result = eval(expression);
  document.getElementById('display').value = result;

  let previosResultadosDiv = document.getElementById('previosResultados');
  previosResultadosDiv.innerHTML += "<p>" + expression + " = " + result + "</p>";
}

function borrarCaracter() {
  let display = document.getElementById('display').value;
  document.getElementById('display').value = display.substring(0, display.length - 1);
}

function borrarHistorial() {
  document.getElementById('previosResultados').innerHTML = '';
}
<div class="calculator">
  <input type="text" id="display" readonly>

  <table>

    <div class="previos-resultados" id="previosResultados"></div>

    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;"><input type="button" value="Borrar Historial" onclick="borrarHistorial()"></div>
</div>
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="agregarDisplay('7')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="agregarDisplay('8')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="agregarDisplay('9')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="agregarDisplay('/')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="agregarDisplay('4')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="agregarDisplay('5')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="agregarDisplay('6')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="agregarDisplay('*')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="agregarDisplay('1')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="agregarDisplay('2')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="agregarDisplay('3')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="agregarDisplay('-')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="C" onclick="limpiarDisplay()"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="agregarDisplay('0')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="agregarDisplay('.')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="agregarDisplay('+')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4"><input type="button" value="DEL" onclick="borrarCaracter()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4"><input type="button" value="=" onclick="calcular()"></td>
</tr>
</table>




Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte tienes que explicar mejor tu pregunta. ¿Qué datos quieres guardar y dónde? Qué significa que al presionar el botón por segunda vez te de el mismo número? Haz colocado el código de una calculadora en Javascript, si mal no entiendo tu pregunta, quieres un botón de Memoria, como los que traen algunas calculadoras físicas. Si ese es el caso, por favor haz clic en [edit] y añade más detalles de tu duda y muestra lo que has intentado hacer hasta ahora, explicando el error o errores y el resultado esperado.

En general, las calculadoras guardan en memoria el último número ingresado. El tema es que tú vas ingresando expresiones que están compuestas de operandos (números) y operadores.
Si en tu display aparece 435, el último número es 435 (fácil). Pero qué pasa cuando aparece 34+52+7/3*3 aquí el último número es 3. Para conseguir separar el último número, puedes hacer un split al display cuyo separador puede ser cualquiera de los operadores, esto retornará un array de operandos, el último es el que guardas:
function getUtimoNumero(){
  const separators = /[+\-\/\*]/;
  return  document.getElementById('display').value.split(separators).at(-1);
}

Luego para guardarlos, puedes usar una variable o un array. Te daré un ejemplo usando este último


const Memoria = [];

function getUtimoNumero(){
  const separators = /[+\-\/\*]/;
  return  document.getElementById('display').value.split(separators).at(-1);
}
function guardarEnMemoria(){
 Memoria.unshift(getUtimoNumero());
 imprimirMemoria();
}
function imprimirMemoria(){
 MemoriaOutput.innerHTML="";
 for(let m of Memoria){
   const li = document.createElement("li");
   li.innerText = m;
   MemoriaOutput.append(li);
 }
}


function agregarDisplay(value) {
  document.getElementById('display').value += value;
}

function limpiarDisplay() {
  document.getElementById('display').value = '';
}



function calcular() {
  let expression = document.getElementById('display').value;
  let result = eval(expression);
  document.getElementById('display').value = result;

  let previosResultadosDiv = document.getElementById('previosResultados');
  previosResultadosDiv.innerHTML += "<p>" + expression + " = " + result + "</p>";
}

function borrarCaracter() {
  let display = document.getElementById('display').value;
  document.getElementById('display').value = display.substring(0, display.length - 1);
}

function borrarHistorial() {
  document.getElementById('previosResultados').innerHTML = '';
}
<div class="calculator">
  <input type="text" id="display" readonly>

  <table>

    <div class="previos-resultados" id="previosResultados"></div>

    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;"><input type="button" value="Borrar Historial" onclick="borrarHistorial()"></div>

<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="agregarDisplay('7')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="agregarDisplay('8')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="agregarDisplay('9')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="agregarDisplay('/')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="agregarDisplay('4')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="agregarDisplay('5')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="agregarDisplay('6')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="agregarDisplay('*')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="agregarDisplay('1')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="agregarDisplay('2')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="agregarDisplay('3')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="agregarDisplay('-')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="C" onclick="limpiarDisplay()"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="agregarDisplay('0')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="agregarDisplay('.')"></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="agregarDisplay('+')"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4"><input type="button" value="DEL" onclick="borrarCaracter()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4"><input type="button" value="=" onclick="calcular()"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Guardar en Memoria" onclick="guardarEnMemoria()">
<h4>Memoria</h4>
<ul id="MemoriaOutput"></ul>




Puedes usar una variable de javascript para almacenar un valor y recuperarla de esa variable en cualquier momento, durante la misma sesión del navegador, es decir, mientras no se recargue la página.
He preparado un ejemplo simple con un input en el que puedes ingresar un valor numérico y dos botones, uno para guardar el valor que esté en el input y otro para recuperar dicho valor, de nuevo, al mismo input.
Utilizo la variable memoria para almacenar el valor. Creo que el código de las funciones se auto explica.
Para probarlo, da clic en "Ejecutar". Ingresa un valor en el input y dale clic en "Guardar". Puedes borrar el valor del input, o ingresar valores nuevos. Cuando hagas clic en "Recuperar", va a colocar en el input el último valor que habías guardado.


const inputNumero = document.getElementById("numero");
let memoria="";

function guardar() {
  memoria = inputNumero.value;
}

function recuperar() {
  inputNumero.value = memoria;
}
<input type="number" id="numero">
<button type="button" onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button>
<button type="button" onclick="recuperar()">Recuperar</button>



Si tienes dudas, no dudes en dejar un comentario.

yo te sugiero ir guardando en numero en un input del tipo hidden, y ahi evaluar si el numero que guarde es el mismo al ingresado, entonces pasarlo a otro input tipo hidden que este sea para ti la memoria. cuando este numero cambie es por que han digitado de forma consecutiva otro numero.

Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.. Por favor mira [answer]
